# Lightning Action on Opportunity Product

Tags: lightning, opportunity-lineitem

I need to add a Lightning action on Opportunity Product.
After some research, I have found that it is not possible.

Anyone ever got this issue?
Any workaround?

Comment: If you found it's not possible, why are you asking if it's possible?

Comment: @sfdcfox: Just trying my luck 'cause why not. ;) So, no workaround according to you?